# Always displaying spans under each other with CSS

Tags: html, css, layout, line-breaks

I have this concept: https://jsfiddle.net/berhqd9a/

First: How can I achieve to make foo1 and foo2 be displayed under each other? I thought, that's what the `display: block` should do?

Second: How can I achieve to make the long foo break instead of ignoring the div's border?

Comment: @all, including everyone answering this question: use code snippets to place code on this site, instead of jsfiddle.

Comment: `inline-block` acts like a block but let you put a `block` element in a single line. `display: block` will move it to the next line as you suppose. You should try it before ask. To make the long text go to the next line just use `word-wrap: break-word`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Pugazh/berhqd9a/2/)

1. `display: block` can be used to show each span as a block or you can use `<br>` to break the line and bring elements to next line.
2. `word-wrap: break-word;` will break the long text.

```css
#main {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
}
.wrapper {
  display: inline;
}
span {
  display: block;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <p class="wrapper">
    <span>foo1</span>
    <span>foo2</span>
    <span>loooooooooooooooong foooooooooooooooooooo</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/berhqd9a/1/

to break the long text you should use  `word-wrap: break-word;`and also use `display:block` to make foo1 and foo2 be displayed under each other, you can also use `width:100%` with `display:inline-block`

```
span {
      display: block;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: Wow, simply using `block` for the inner element was the solution? I was way too fixed on making the wrapper displayed as `block`... Also I didn't know the `word-wrap`-property. Good to know that now. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

**First** `display: block` - Displays an element as a block element

**Second:** because the text doesn´t have space you need to force the the text to break apart using this rule `word-break: break-all;`or `word-wrap: break-word;`

**CSS**

```
#main {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}

span {
  display: block;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/berhqd9a/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Froxx,

right now you are having

```
span {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

instead of

```
span {
   display: block;
}
```